# How to add many-to-many relationships through a form?

Tags: php, mysql

My database holds the following data:

```
fish
---
id
name
cooking_type_id
---

cooking_type
---
id
name
---

cooking_type_relationships
---
fish_id
cooking_type_id
---
```

I'm trying to create a form where you add a fish to the database. It all works fine, but I have a problem when adding many relationships. Through the form I've made a check box list with all the cooking types where the user clicks all the cooking types that suits the fish. But how do I query the database so it creates the relationships nicely?

Here's the code for creating the check-box list:

```
include 'conn.php';
    echo "<ul class='cooking-list'>";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cooking_type c"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {            
    // run through the results from the database, generating the checkboxes 
    echo "\n\t<li>"; 
    echo "<input id='".$row['name']."' type='checkbox' name'type_id'><p>{$row['name']}</p>"; 
    echo "</li>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    } 
    echo "</ul>"; 
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Edit: I'm not getting the query to work properly. I'm a little confused at this point. Here's the query I'm trying to post:

```
include 'conn.php';
mysqli_query($mysqli, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = "INSERT INTO fish (name, image, about, season_id)
      VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[image]', '$_POST[about]', '$_POST[season_id]');
      INSERT INTO cooking_type_relationships (fish_id, cooking_type_id)
      VALUES (mysqli_insert_id, cooking_type_id);"


$mysqli->query($query);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, you want us to figure out the relation / schema between the fish and dishes/cooking type?

Comment: You should consider using PDO instead of mysqli functions. The relationships should be setup using foreign keys and selected using joins on those keys. It may be beneficial for you to learn to build into a framework- which can handle much of this heavy lifting, including relationships. Read up on laravel, phalcon, or codeigniter.

Comment: From your description it doesn't sound like a many-to-many relationship. You have one fish that can have more cooking types....that is a one-to-many relationship and you can just make a foreign key in your cooking type that points to a fish (the foreign key is an id that points to the fish)

Comment: @broch This is not true, what if multiple fish have the same cooking type?

Comment: @marijn0r hmmm or if one fish has more cooking types...yes I see your point

Comment: Seems plausible to me. Last night I had fried cod. Tomorrow night I'm going to try baking it.

Comment: Remove cooking type id from fish table and then you will have good `many to many` structure.

Comment: @MikelBitson what's the advantage with using PDO here? My knowledge of it is very limited and I'm a little frightened by it since the syntax is very different.

Comment: @broch@marinj0r I see you understand the problem correctly, but how to solve it? :) It seems like an easy task in theory but once I had to deal with it practically it gets more difficult.

Comment: @MstrQKN If you post the code you have tried it would be easier to help.

Comment: @MstrQKN My suggestion for PDO was honestly based on two facts: PDO is object-oriented and enforces good OOP practices and PDO prevents SQL injection by sending the query and variables separately. (These are my top two benefits, but there are countless others- such as returning data specifically as you want it so you do not have to parse the data before using it.) Give something like this a quick read: http://goo.gl/gUHK4l 

EDIT: Just a heads up- you're going to need to have the relationships figured out, PDO will not handle that for you, it's just better than using mysqli.

Comment: @broch I've added the code I'm trying to use.

Comment: I have updated my answer below to comment on your added code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to insert data into two tables, the fish table and the cooking_types_relationships table.

Pseudo code:

```
insert into fish values (a, b, c);
insert into cooking_types_relationships values (mysqli_insert_id, cooking_type_id);
```

The trick here is using [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: This seems like the perfect solution! I'm trying to get the code going now and will get back with either the solution or additional questions :) Thanks!

Comment: I tried it but can't get it to work. Can you take a brief look at it and see if you can find out what's wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to execute two queries. The first one inserting the fish -> this generates a mysqli_insert_id -> use this id to insert a value in cooking_types_relationships. That would be the second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make 2 requests in one query. It is due to a security issue.
Always quote your keys when you get values from $_POST
And I assume that in your mysql tables your id column has the primary and auto_increment flag.

Then try to do the following:

```
include 'conn.php';
mysqli_query($mysqli, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = "INSERT INTO fish (name, image, about, season_id)
  VALUES ('$_POST['name']', '$_POST['image']', '$_POST['about']', '$_POST['season_id']')";

mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

$query = "INSERT INTO cooking_type_relationships (fish_id, cooking_type_id)
  VALUES (". $id . ", ".$cooking_type_id.")";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

You have to find the correct $cooking_type_id in a similar manner as the fish id. Or maybe you already know it if it is a fixed list of cooking types

You have also confused the procedural and the object oriented way of making a query. $mysqli->query() is object oriented and I don't think that is what you need.

Just remember to filter your $_POST values before using it in production. As other mentioned look at PDO prepared statements

When you want to get the data out again you could do an inner join like so:

```
SELECT * FROM fish 
INNER JOIN cooking_type_relationships ON fish.id=fish_id
INNER JOIN cooking_type ON cooking_type_id=cooking_type.id
```

If a fish do not have any cooking types but you still want it to show up as a result you just change the inner joins to LEFT JOIN

Comment: Thanks @broch this is a great answer. I'm new to this so I'm trying to grasp all the info. I find PDO pretty confusing but I'll try my best to learn some :) I'll update this thread asap

Comment: You are welcome ;) You don't have to use PDO although it is the safest option. You can also use filter_var to filter your strings before inserting them into the database. Check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
(And greetings from Copenhagen. I saw you are from Göteborg :) )